# Immutable recursive binary search of a generic array

Tags: algorithm, f#

I am new to F#. Is the following code, which represents about three hours of work, a canonical way [to achieve binary search?](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/p/challenge-binary-search) If not, how can it be improved for readability and maintainability?

```
let binarySearch (array: 'a[]) (target: 'a) = 
    let rec search min max =
        match (min, max) with 
        | (min, max) when max < min -> -1 
        | _ -> 
            let guess = ((min + max) / 2);
            match array.[guess] with
            | x when x = target -> guess 
            | x when x < target -> search (guess + 1) (max) 
            | _ -> search (min) (guess - 1) 
    search (0) (array.Length - 1)
```

Aspects that I already like:

- hiding the recursive function within the non-recursive function.
- using pattern matching instead of `if-else-then`, [based on suggestions here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/control-flow-expressions/),
- accepting generic types with `` `a ``.

Answer (score 2):

I would strive for symmetry:

```
        match array.[guess] with
        | x when x > target -> search (min) (guess - 1) 
        | x when x < target -> search (guess + 1) (max) 
        | _ -> guess
```

Comment: I agree with your symmetry argument, but I think the last match should return guess and not x

Answer (score 0):

This is abuse of pattern matching. Look: there are no actual patterns! You misunderstood what Mr. Wlaschin is saying in the link you provided: pattern matching is not *always* better than `if-then-else`, only in cases when there are actual patterns. In this case, `if-then-else` leads to much more comprehensible code:

```
let binarySearch (array: 'a[]) (target: 'a) = 
    let rec search min max =
        if max < min then -1 
        else
            let guess = ((min + max) / 2);
            let x = array.[guess]
            if   x > target then search (min) (guess - 1) 
            elif x < target then search (guess + 1) (max) 
            else guess

    search (0) (array.Length - 1)
```

Comment: That reminds me of Mr. Wlashin's comment: "avoid using imperative control flow *when you are learning to think functionally*." [emphasis added]. Once I've learned to think functionally, using `if-else-then` might be better. A suggestion for your answer: I think it's more realistic to say that `if-else-then` might be a better approach, rather than saying that this is an abuse of pattern matching.

Comment: `if-then-else` is not inherently "imperative control flow". It might look like that to the uninitiated, because it looks, on the surface, similar to constructs widely used in imperative languages. However, `if-then-else` of F# is different from similar construct of C# in a critical way: it is an expression, not a"command". In this capacity, it is widely used even in mathematics, e.g. "modulus of x is x if x >= 0, and -x otherwise".

Comment: "Look: there are no patterns." The existence of guards for pattern matching suggests that guards are a certain type of pattern.

Comment: No, they are not. Guards and patterns are two different things. The point is, if your pattern-matching expression has nothing but guards, it is equivalent to `if-then` in power, but is longer and  less readable.

Comment: This corroborates what you said: "Pattern matching is based on patterns only -- it can't use functions or other kinds of conditional tests." https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/ It then suggests guards as an alternative when patterns are not available. So, as you said, they are two different things. The same article does `fizzBuzz` entirely with guards. It seems that doing a match with entirely guards is an alternative to `if-then-else`, and that the choice between the two is stylistic.